# AngularJS - Components on Header Bar

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

If i put a *select* on *nav bar*, when I change the *selected item* the *expression* doesn't show the new value. Why?

If i put the *expression* inside the *ion-nav-buttons*, it works. What is it wrong?

Here is my page source code:

```
<ion-view>
<ion-nav-buttons side="right">
    <select ng-model="idLegaSelezionata" ng-options="lega.ID_LEGA as lega.NOME for lega in leghe"></select> 
</ion-nav-buttons>

<ion-nav-buttons side="left">

    <button menu-toggle="left" class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon">     </button>

</ion-nav-buttons> 


<ion-content class="padding has-header" ng-model="idLegaSelezionata">
  {{idLegaSelezionata}}
</ion-content>


</ion-view>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `cache-view="false"` on the `<ion-view>` tag.